# Xcode warning about precision

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
CategoryLoaded =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CategorySaved"];
```

Here is the error:

```
"Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `CategoryLoaded`.

Comment: (a) it's a warning not an error, (b) the warning tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

From the SDK header:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So you see, `NSInteger`, which is what you get as the return type from `integerForKey:`, can be either an int or a long, which is different sizes.  You're building 64 bit, most likely, which means you're assigning a long to what is, apparently, an int.

So either change the type of `CategoryLoaded` to be big enough:

```
NSInteger CategoryLoaded;
```

...or use a c-style cast that says "shut up I know what I'm doing":

```
CategoryLoaded = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CategorySaved"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'`

One way to deal with this is to declare `CategoryLoaded` as `NSInteger` rather than `int`.

Another is to store the number as a `NSNumber` using `+numberWithInt:` and use `-objectForKey:` instead of `-integerForKey:`.